How do I drop multiple rows from a chosen column in a pandas dataframe?
I have a dataframe relating to Olympic sports, along with the Nations competing and number/ranking of medals won, etc. My list of sports includes both summer and winter games sports, and I want to create a new dataframe showing just the summer sports.
So, I have a list of the rows I want to remove from the column "Sport", including things like "luge", "speed skating", "curling" etc. There are a lot of items in this list and I have tried various approaches to the drop() function using axis=0, but I can't find a way to cut these rows ( I'm getting errors along the lines of two many arguments etc)
Any advice would be gratefully received!
I have tried various approaches, including:
newdf=df.drop("luge", "curling", "speed skating", "skeleton bob", "ski jump", "cross country skiing", "bobsleigh", axis = 0, inplace=True)

And:
newdf=df.drop(["sport":"luge", "curling", "speed skating", "skeleton bob", "ski jump", "cross country skiing", "bobsleigh"], axis = 0, inplace=True)


Just spotted a typo in my code snippet! that should be a comma after axis=0 in both examples. Sorry!

Please be explicit, what are the exact errors with the complete error traceback? Please [edit] the question if you need to update something.

This first approach cannot work, the second one with the list should be fine, provided the columns exist in the first place. If not, add errors='ignore'. Be aware that inplace=True won't return anything but update the DataFrame in place.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

did you try to drop every row separately? maybe you have mistake in one name. I see "sport":"luge" which is incorrect value.

if you have it as value in some column but not as index then you may need something similar to mask = df["Sport"] not in ["luge", "curling", "speed skating", "skeleton bob", "ski jump", "cross country skiing", "bobsleigh"] to select it. And this gives mask (with values True/False) which you can use to select rows  newdf = df[mask]

BTW: drop works with column's names or with index values but not with values in other columns.

To remove rows with multiple undesired conditions you can use isin function.
import pandas as pd
sport_data = ["luge", "curling", "speed skating", "skeleton bob", "ski jump", "cross country skiing", "bobsleigh"]
exclude = ["luge", "speed skating", "curling"]
df=pd.DataFrame({"Sport":sport_data, "Number":list(range(len(sport_data)))})
newdf = df[df["Sport"].isin(exclude) == False]

Input:



Sport
Number




luge
0


curling
1


speed skating
2


skeleton bob
3


ski jump
4


cross country skiing
5


bobsleigh
6



Output:



Sport
Number




skeleton bob
3


ski jump
4


cross country skiing
5


bobsleigh
6



Note: In the commnets @furas suggested good alternative, where:
df = df[df["Sport"].isin(exclude) == False] can be replaced with df = df[~df["Sport"].isin(exclude)].

it would be good if you would describe it in question - explain isin. BTW: you can use ~ to reverse selection df[ ~df["Sport"].isin(exclude) ]

@furas thank you for your advice I've added it to the answer as a note.
